# Paradox in calculating Partial Derivative wrt xy.

Tags: partial-derivative, paradoxes

I am trying to calculate
$\frac{\partial (xy^2)}{\partial (xy)}$.

To calculate this I am trying to substitute expressions in $\alpha, \beta$ instead of $x, y$ in two independent methods.

**Method-1**:

Suppose $x = \sqrt{\alpha \beta}$ and $y = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}$.

So $xy^2 = {\alpha}^{3/2}{\beta}^{-1/2}$ and $xy = \alpha$.

$\frac{\partial (xy^2)}{\partial (xy)}$ = $\frac{\partial ({\alpha}^{3/2}{\beta}^{-1/2})}{\partial \alpha}$
$= {\beta}^{-1/2} \cdot \frac{3\alpha^{1/2}}{2} = \frac{3y}{2}$

**Method-2**:

Suppose $x = \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{\beta}}$ and $y = \sqrt{\beta}$

$\frac{\partial (xy^2)}{\partial (xy)}$ = $\frac{\partial (\alpha \sqrt{\beta})}{\partial (\alpha)}
= \sqrt{\beta} = y
$

What is wrong about the methods I am using? After all it is basic substitution.

EDIT:
I see. The actual motivation for the question was a problem in 2-D vector calculus. I wanted to calculate
$div(\overrightarrow{v})$ in polar coordinates. So is it wrong to write:

$\frac{\partial{v_x}}{\partial{x}} $
= $ \frac{\partial ({v_r cos\theta - v_{\theta} sin\theta})}
{\partial({r cos\theta})}$

where $ v_r$  and  $v_{\theta}$ are components of $\overrightarrow{v}$ along $\overrightarrow{r}$ and $\overrightarrow{\theta}$

Comment: It makes no sense to differentiate with respect to $xy$.

Comment: Is there a specific constraint on what we can calculate partial derivative wrt?

Comment: You can take partial derivatives with respect to the different arguments of the function. That's it.

Comment: @CaptainAmerica Yes. The idea of a derivative is a linear model of the difference to $f(x+h)-f(x)$ in terms of $h$.

Comment: @HansLundmark , copper.hat Thanks for the response. Please try to look at the EDIT

Comment: To transform from Cartesian to polar coordinates, you have to use the multivariable chain rule. What you've written is not correct. The formula for divergence in polar coordinates is well-known (take $F_z=0$ here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Cylindrical_coordinates) and the derivation can also be found in many places.